# Windows not booting after removing the partition containing ubuntu

Tags: boot

I had windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot.
Now I removed the partition containing Ubuntu and after doing so, I am not able to boot in windows and it shows internal hard disk is not available.
Help me out of this crisis.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? If UEFI, you just need to go into UEFI and choose to boot Windows as default. If BIOS you should have installed  the Windows boot loader to the MBR before deleting Ubuntu partition. You need a Windows repairCD or flash drive. Or you can use Boot-Repair. http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on OR: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. Im not one hundred percent since i don't have win 10 but for win 7 and 8 the disk is the answer, read bios screen as it starts there should be a boot option  i think its f2 then repair. Hope this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Windows Recovery mode (F8 method) only works IF you are able to get windows to start a boot. However, the asker seems to be missing a bootloader because it is not even giving him/her the option to boot into windows.

Comment: Yea...its not showing the bootloader.

Comment: The problem iam having is due to the fact that I deleted the Linux and with that the grub boot loader is gone... And now to boot with windows I have to have mbr. But I don't know how to tell  the hard disk to boot windows through mbr.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)